# Confusion on MS SQL Server Locking behavior for delete from Microsoft's Docs

Tags: sql-server

In [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/delete-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15#locking-behavior) on Locking behavior they state the following.

> By default, a DELETE statement always acquires an intent exclusive
> (IX) lock on the table object it modifies, and holds that lock until
> the transaction completes. With an intent exclusive (IX) lock, no
> other transactions can modify data; read operations can take place
> only with the use of the NOLOCK hint or read uncommitted isolation
> level.

I'm confused by their comment on Updates and Reads being blocked. Its my understanding that a **Intent exclusive  Shared lock** will be taken **on the table** for reads and that ****Intent Shared**** and **Intent Exclusive locks**  are **compatible**. [See Lock Compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-ver15#lock_compatibility)

Its currently my understanding that these locks are compatible and that multiple actions can be performed ie (Updates, Reads, Deletes) on the same table provided they target different rows and no lock escalation takes place.

I've tried to find a answer to this but seeing as my confusion comes from Microsoft official document, I haven't found a answer that restores my confidence in my mental model, I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.  That doc is wrong.  I've submitted a [PR](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/pull/6613) to get the doc fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the response and helping other developers avoid this confusion in the future.. I'll up-vote as soon as i have enough rep.